# How do I add text search indexes to my Google App Engine app in Python?

Tags: google-app-engine, search

I've read about SearchableModel (e.g., [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#3cWyxpJc0WU/trunk/thirdparty/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/search/__init__.py&q=searchablemodel&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc), [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/f64eacbd31629668/8dac5499bd58a6b7?lnk=gst&q=searchablemodel), and [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=searchablemodel)).  Looks like it has some real limitations, e.g. no ranking (!).

I've seen [gae-search](http://gae-full-text-search.appspot.com/).  It looks like its author is too busy to provide support anymore.

Finally, there is a [filed issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=217).

What have people used, and what are your experiences?

Answer (score 1):

SearchableModel. They improve it behind the scenes, so we don't have to.Advice is don't index private fields such as email adresses. Your model also can use geospatial index

```
class Article(GeoModel, search.SearchableModel)
 text=db.TextProperty(verbose_name="text")
 email=db.EmailProperty(indexed=False,verbose_name="Email")#optional, don't index
```

Answer (score 1):

If you end up needing to roll-your-own full-text search solution (which i would not advise), have a look at [Whoosh](http://whoosh.ca). It's written in pure python, so you should be able to get it to run on GAE rather easily. You *will* have to write classes to handle storage in the GAE datastore though. Normally it uses files.